# PDFBox / WordUtils: Strange characters in populated PDF form Text Box

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox to populate the fields in a PDF form, by getting a PDTextbox and then calling 'setValue'. I'm also manually wrapping the text using WordUtils.wrap (Apache Commons) I'm finding that certain combinations of characters, specifically involving parenthesis, are causing strange characters to output in the PDF Text Field. For example:

*Pt. states "I was turning and my knee twisted under me and I fell and I felt something move (in my knee). When I tried to stand up I collapsed because it was so painful."*

is displayed in the text field as

*Pt. states "I was turning and my knee twisted under me and I fell and I felt something move (in my) Tj 0 -13 T"*

whereas the string: 
*Testing (character) encoding (issue) (knee) my knee)*

causes nothing to be displayed at all. The first string (re: the knee) doesn't wrap correctly either, until you click on the text and then it displays correctly (I've seen other text field issues that seem to resolve themselves when you click on the text box).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public static void setTextboxValue(PDAcroForm form, String fieldName, String value) throws Exception {
    String newValue = "";
    if (value != null)
        newValue = value;

    // Clean up CR / LF characters, replace with newlines.
    newValue = newValue.replace("\r", "");

    PDTextbox box = getTextbox(form, fieldName);
    if (box != null)
        box.setValue(newValue);
}

public static void setTextboxValue(PDAcroForm form, String fieldName, String value, int wrapLength) throws Exception {
    String newValue = "";
    if (value != null)
        newValue = value;

    setTextboxValue(form, fieldName, WordUtils.wrap(newValue, wrapLength, "\n", true));
}
```

In this case I'm calling `setTextboxValue(form, "FIELDNAME", object.getDescription(), 100);` I assumed it was an issue caused by how/where I'm calling WordUtils.wrap() except for the testing string shouldn't wrap anyway, and if I remove the parenthesis from the knee string it displays and wraps just fine.

Any thoughts?!

Answer (score 0):

According to [PDFBOX-276](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-276) and [PDFBOX-716](http://markmail.org/thread/b6vaw2isfi67hcux), pdfbox has a history of mishandling the RIGHT parenthesis marks.  It is my understanding that the `)` character gets rendered as `\`.  Because `\` is the escape character, all kinds of crazy stuff happens to the single character or characters after the `\` function as control characters and of course would not be printed.  This would totally explain your situation

So here are some suggestions:

1. Look at different versions of PDFBox possibly?  The errors I mention are from 2010, so hopefully they would have this issue fixed by now.  PDFBOX-276 added a patch to the code at that time.  I believe PDFBOX-716 was a patch to remove the PDFBOX-276 patch.
2. Since you are outputting into PDF form, try to escape all occurrences of right parenthesis and see if that helps.

So long answer short, it is a bug of PDFBox and hopefully they have fixed it by now.